# How can I render contents inside a shape as a texture on the shape itself? As well as teleporting an object from one side of a mesh to the opposite?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a space game and I want the game to take place inside of a sphere or cube. I want the walls of the shape to render what's inside on the inside walls so it seems like endless space. Once the illusion of endless is in place I want to teleport the player if they touch the game space shape and teleport them seamlessly to the opposite side of the shape.

Edit: I just had an idea of how to teleport how I want. Maybe using ray casting to cast a ray behind the player and where ever that hits when they touch the edge of the shape to teleport to?

Comment: These are two different problems. If understand what you need (1) you can you a skybox (2) place a box collider in your scene and teleport the player on a trigger exit event (with a bit of maths)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what "opposite side" means. But anyway, with the box collider bounds and the player's position (via it's collider) you can do the maths you need (no need to raycast)

Comment: If you're rendering what's outside the box, then why do you have the box at all? If you're looking for a teleport mechanic then just make a box and turn the `MeshRenderer` off, and then you get to keep the collider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer question one I used a render texture. It's very close to the effect I want I just have to play with the perspective like they do with portals in portal 1 and 2.

To answer the my second question I went with raycasting. The player flys around in a sphere and casts a ray behind itself. Once the player hits the collision of the sphere they teleport to the point of the raycast. This works perfectly only for the fact when the player reverses on the sphere collider they escape the sphere flawlessly.